# primefaces not refreshing the page when using confirmdialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to create a menu with a logout link in it.

I used this code:

```
<p:menubar>
            <p:menuitem value="Logout" oncomplete="confirmation.show()"/>

            <f:facet name="options">
                <p:inputText style="margin-right:10px" />
                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Logout" icon="ui-icon-extlink" />
            </f:facet>
</p:menubar>

<p:confirmDialog message="Are you sure you want to logout?"
            showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="explode"
            header="Logout" severity="alert"
            widgetVar="confirmation">

            <p:commandButton value="Yes Sure" update="messages"
                oncomplete="confirmation.hide()"
                actionListener="#{authBean.logout}"
                 />
            <p:commandButton value="Not Yet" onclick="confirmation.hide()"
                type="button" />

</p:confirmDialog>
```

Here is my login and logout methods from authBean:

```
public String login() {
    try{
    UserService userService = new UserService();
    User currentUser = userService.findUser(username, password);
    System.out.println(currentUser);
    if (currentUser != null) {
        HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("currentUser", currentUser);
        return "index";
    } 
    else return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, e.toString(), e.toString());
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        return null;
    }

}

public String logout() {
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    session.invalidate();
    return "login";
}
```

Here is my faces-config:

```
    <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

My problem is that when I press Yes on confirm dialog the page doesn't refresh to welcome.xhtml. I have to press on same menu button or any other button so the page updates. I want that it updates to welcome.xhtml after I pressed Yes on confirm dialog.

Comment: You're returning `"login"` as outcome. This doesn't match.

Comment: did you get answer for this question? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after much reading and try and error I came to the conclusion that in the commandbutton you have to use action instead of actionListener if the method you are calling does a redirect.

And also look at this post about h:form that is needed also.

[PrimeFaces commandButton in confirmDialog not calling backing bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14281605/primefaces-commandbutton-in-confirmdialog-not-calling-backing-bean)

Good Luck!